# unable to handle comet based thread at server side

Tags: java, multithreading, comet

I am working on a comet based session logout system,Actually i want to check user session is active or not without sending  ajax request every time to the server.so when user login first time, a request goes to the server(Servlet)  and hold until sessionout(a thread check),how can a thread handle session for every user at server.unable to implement with thread,any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think a thread checks whole session guys every 1 min(or less) and just remove the expired sessions, and also this is hardly possible that each session has its own life thread that it makes the server heavy.
if you are trying to doing same, you need a thread (daemon mode will be okay) that after a 1min sleep checks all sessions, something like this

```
class Foo implements Runnable{
List<Session> sessions;
public void run(){
while(true){
try{
Thread.sleep(60000);
synchronized(sessions){
for(Session sx:sessions){
 if(sx.isExpired()){sx.dispose();sessions.remove(sx);}
}
}
}catch(Exception e){}
}
}
}
```

I hope I got the question correct and could give some hand :)

Comment: if 100 users login at a time then 100 request will be on hold, so how can servlet response(comet response) to that particular user which session has been destroyed

Comment: do you mean comet response as `keep alive` connection?

Comment: yes, how to handle comet response for that particular session

Answer (score 0):

So my suggestion is keep every session in a global reference, like a list in a singleton class, then the class also run a thread that refresh each session each 1 min, something like this, BUT I DON NOT KNOW that the server refreshes the session expire time with HttpServeltRequest reference or with HttpSession itself, anyway so you would to keey either request or session references.

```
public class SessionHolder implements Runnable{
private List<HttpSession> sessions;
public void addSession(HttpSession s){sessions.add(s);}
public void removeSession(HttpSession s){Session.remove}
public void run(){
while (true){
try{
Thread.sleep(60000);
//refreshing sessions
for(HttpSession sx:sessions){
sx.setAttribute("noExpire","me again");//this may causes to refresh the session expire time
}
}catch(Exception e){}
}
}
}
```